# Questions about Levy measure in the canonical representation of infinitely divisible distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, infinite-divisibility

Let $X$ be a random variable with infinitely divisible and symmetric distribution $F$ distributed on $\mathbb{R}$.

It is well known that the characteristic function of $X$ has  a canonical representation of the form:
\begin{align}
\phi(t)=e^{  -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t^2-\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1-cos(tx) ) dV(x)}
\end{align}
where $V$ is a non-negative  measure  such that $V(\{0\})=0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \min(1,x^2) dV(x)<\infty$.

The measure $V$ is called Levy measure and here we are interested in its properties.

My questions are:

1. Under what condition on $F$  is $V$ an absolutely continuous measure? For example, is absolute continuity of $F$ enough?
2. Can we say anything about $V$ based on the tail behavior of $F$?
3. Can we say anything about $V$ based on the tail behavior of $\phi(t)$?
4. I know it is generally difficult to determine $V$ but what can generally be said about $V$ from basic properties of $F$ and $\phi(t)$?

   Also, any good reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would discuss your questions partially under the following condition:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\,dF(x)<\infty, \tag{1}$$
or equivalently $\varphi^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists and finite or $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2\,dV(y)<\infty$. Let $K(x)\triangleq\int_{-\infty}^x y^2\,dV(y)<\infty$, it is easy to obtain the following expressions:
\begin{gather}
-(\log\varphi(t))^{\prime\prime}=\sigma^2+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(tx)dK(x),\\
-\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T (\log\varphi(t))^{\prime\prime} dt =\sigma^2,\\
\psi(t)\triangleq -(\log\varphi(t))^{\prime\prime}-\sigma^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tx)\,dK(x).\tag{2}
\end{gather}
Now from the inversion formula of characteristic functions we have following conclusion: Under (1),
\begin{gather} \int_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi(t)|\,dt<\infty \quad\Rightarrow\quad
dK(x)\ll d\lambda\quad \Rightarrow \quad dV(x)\ll d\lambda\;(\text{$V$ has density})\\
\begin{aligned}\int x^{2n}dF(x)<\infty \quad &\Rightarrow \quad \varphi^{(2n)}(0)\; \text{exists and finite}\\
&\Rightarrow \quad \psi^{(2n)}(0)\; \text{exists and finite}\\
&\Rightarrow \quad \int x^{2n}\,dV(x)<\infty, \qquad n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{aligned} 
\end{gather}

Comment: Hi.  I finally got this book from the library. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the exact theorem that would say under what condition the measure $V$ is absolutely continuous. Can you point this out to me?

Comment: @Boby， Sorry， I confused your questions. You concerned is the sufficient conditions of $V$ is absolute continuous, and the book given is the the conditions of $F$ is  absolute continuous. I am sorry to bother you.

Comment: In your proof $\psi(t)$ is a characteristic function of the distribution $K(x)$, correct?  Or is it only a cosine transform? Of course, cosine transform and characteristic function are equivalent if the distribution $K(x)$ is symmetric.  Do we know here that $K(x)$ is symmetric? Does symmetry of $F(x)$ imply symmetry of $K(x)$? Thanks.

Comment: @Boby As a measure, $dK(x)$ is symmetry. $K(x)$ and $K(x)+c$ define same measure.  Distribution $F$ is symmetry($F(-x-)=1-F(x)$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi(-t)=\varphi(t)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\psi(-t)=\psi(t)$ $\Leftrightarrow$  $dK(x)$ is symmetry.

Comment: After equation (1) when you say: "...or equivalently $\phi^{"}(0)$ exists and is finite  or $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 dV(y)$ ."      This sentence seems incomplete.  What did you mean to say about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 dV(y)$?? Did you mean to say that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 dV(y)$?$ is finite?

Comment: @Boby Thank you, you are right. I revised it.

Comment: Can you tell me how the existence of $\phi^{"}(0)$ implies that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 dV(y)<\infty$?

Comment: $\phi^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists $\implies$ $(\log \phi(t))^{\prime\prime}|_{t=0}$ exists $\implies$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dV(y)<\infty$, the last step is similar to ``$\phi^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists $\implies$ $\int x^2dF(x)<\infty$''.

Comment: Final question. How do we know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(t)| dt <\infty$?

Comment: @Boby, Thank you for your reply. Since $\psi(t)$ depends $\phi(t)$ and $F$, it is only a sufficient condition of $dV\ll d\lambda$. I hope use it to answer your first question partially (Similarly, we always say that $\int|\phi(t)|dt<\infty\;\implies\; F$ has density).

Comment: Just to clarify, if we were to put this as a theorem then it would say.  { If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 dF(x)< \infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(t)| dt <\infty$, then the measure $V$ has a densidty. }  Is this correct?

Comment: @Boby  Correct! You are right.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Please let me know if you have an idea of how to answering other questions I posed.

Comment: @Boby: 1. The $\int |x|^mdF(x)<+\infty$ is a tail behavior of $F$, so $\int|x|^{2m}dF<\infty \iff \int|X|^{2m}dV<\infty$ partially replied your "Question 2" moments .

Comment: @Boby: 1. The $\int |x|^mdF(x)<+\infty$ is a tail behavior of $F$, so $\int|x|^{2m}dF(x)<\infty \iff \int|x|^{2m}dV(x)<\infty$ partially replied your "Question 2" .    <br/> 2. About the $\int|x|^{p}dV(x)<\infty$, please refer to Sato's book *Levy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* Th2.5.3, p159 and Cor25.8, p162.

Comment: @Boby: 1. The $\int |x|^mdF(x)<+\infty$ is a tail behavior of $F$, so $\int|x|^{2m}dF(x)<\infty \iff \int|x|^{2m}dV(x)<\infty$ partially replied your "Question 2".      <br/> 2. About the $\int|x|^{p}dV(x)<\infty$, please refer to Sato's book *Levy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* Th25.3, p159 and Cor25.8, p162.

Comment: One more question. If $f_K(x)$ is the density of measure $K(x)$, then $f_V(x)=x^2 f_K(x)$ is density of measure $V(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Boby: Yes, $f_V(x)=x^2f_K(x)$, you are right.